# CGContextSetRGBFillColor not working

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, cocos2d-iphone, cgcontext

I am creating sprites from the CGImage I have drawn using the CGContext functions. I have also a color changing mechanism implemented as a menu. But even though I clear the context and change the color the color which is used for drawing remains the same. Do anybody have anyidea what is wrong?

```
CGContextSaveGState(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(40, 40));
    if ([color isEqualToString:@"black"]) {
        CGContextSetRGBFillColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 0,0,0, 1);
    }
    else if ([color isEqualToString:@"red"]) {
        CGContextSetRGBFillColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 1.0,0,0, 1);
    }
    else if ([color isEqualToString:@"green"]) {
        CGContextSetRGBFillColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 0,1.0,0, 1);
    }
    else if ([color isEqualToString:@"blue"]) {
        CGContextSetRGBFillColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 0,0,1.0, 1);
    }
    CGRect rect1 = CGRectMake(0,0,40,40);
    CGContextAddEllipseInRect(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(),rect1);
    CGContextFillPath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    UIImage *myImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    CGContextFlush(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()) ;
    CGContextRestoreGState(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());

    CCSprite *newSprite = [CCSprite spriteWithCGImage:[myImage CGImage] key:@"blackCircle"];
    [itemsArray addObject:newSprite];
    [newSprite setPosition:point];
    [self addChild:newSprite];
```

Comment: Can you add snapshots of what you have and what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure your color variable is being set, and that it is the right encoding of string to pass the isEqualToString test? (i.e are you sure you're actually hitting the code to set the color).

I copied your code above, up to creation of the image from the context, into the viewDidLoad method of a view controller and then added the image into an imageview subview of the view, and the color came out right.

This is the code I put into the viewDidLoad method of a view controller - the view ended up with a blue circle on it, so it seems like your code should work:

```
CGContextSaveGState(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(40, 40));
NSString *color = @"blue";
 if ([color isEqualToString:@"black"]) {
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 1,0,0, 1);
}
else if ([color isEqualToString:@"red"]) {
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 1.0,0,0, 1);
}
else if ([color isEqualToString:@"green"]) {
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 0,1.0,0, 1);
}
else if ([color isEqualToString:@"blue"]) {
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 0,0,1.0, 1);
}
CGRect rect1 = CGRectMake(0,0,40,40);
CGContextAddEllipseInRect(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(),rect1);
CGContextFillPath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
UIImage *myImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
CGContextFlush(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()) ;
CGContextRestoreGState(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());

UIImageView *imgV = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30,30,200,200)];
imgV.image = myImage;
[self.view addSubview:imgV];
```

Comment: Yeah. What you did is right.It works for me to.. For the **First Time** Afterwards when I change the value of color to something else and then execute the block of code. Then there is no change in color. I tried flushing the CGContext. Using stack push pop for CGContext etc.. But no use.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the full colour code parameters like so...

> ```
> CGContextSetRGBFillColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 1.0/255,0.0/255,0.0/255, 1.0);
> ```